# How to get the second data of this JSON in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I get the second data of this JSON - **I am beta.** in jQuery?

```
{"alpha":["I am alpha"],"beta":["I am beta."]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finally I come up with this

**Step 1:** Json parsed,

**Step 2 :** Declared in another string

**Step 3 :** And then looped inside each entry

```
  obj=JSON.parse(data); 
  var error_string=''; 
  $.each(obj, function(entry) { 
  error_string+=obj[entry]+'<br/>'; 
  }); 
  $('#stage').html(error_string); 
  }
```

And then i got the values that is inside, Now i can able to get the values inside the object even for n numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your json is in a string variable as:

```
var data = '{"alpha":["I am alpha"],"beta":["I am beta."]}';
```

You can parse the string as a json object and then access the content like this:

```
json = JSON.parse(data);
//or if you strictly need to use jQuery
json = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(json.alpha[0]);
alert(json.beta[0]);
```

If you don't know which is the json content you can iterate through json object like this:

```
for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(key + " -> " + json[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like: "json.beta[0]"?

Comment: You're right, didn't notice that beta is an array. TY.

Comment: Actually i don't know the json content, so i am iterating, but i am getting error in that , and my console is getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: I then completed it with obj=JSON.parse(data); 
      var error_string=''; 
      $.each(obj, function(entry) { 
      error_string+=obj[entry]+'<br/>'; 
      }); 
      $('#stage').html(error_string); 
      }

Answer (score 0):

You can go through array and search for keys what you want... but dont forget to encode json string

```
$data= json.encode($input)
foreach($data as $key => $val)
       {
         if($key=='beta')
           do something
         else
           do something else
      }
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i have posted my own answer